# Jstring passed to Java is different to what is expected

Tags: java, c, eclipse, java-native-interface

I have a string being passed from a .c file to a java program. The function looks like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_MyJNI_getName(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Name");

}
```

However, in my unit tests it says that "Name" isn't what is being returned.

```
/**
 * test to see if name is retrieved properly
 */
@Test
public void getNameTest1(){
    MyJNI m = new MyJNI();
    assertSame(m.getName(), "Name");
}
```

This test gives this error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected same: <Name> was not:<Name>
```

So I don't understand what the difference is. I'm guessing it is something to do with a null character or line break but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Check the name read from the file. You have to "figure it out"; that's what debuggers are for.

Comment: The read file was not a necessary part of the unit test, I added it in by accident. An honest mistake, but the error still remains after deletion of that line

Comment: Berti, you are new to this site, but when someone answered your question and it works, then click on the number on the left of it to approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertSame(expected, actual)` checks if the objects are the **same**
instance (according to the `==` operator). You got the assertion
error because you compared 2 distinct instances of `String`,
though both with equally looking contents.

You probably want check if the 2 strings are **equal** (according to
the `equals` method). To do this you need to use

```
assertEquals(m.getName(), "Name");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the mistake. Thinking about it now, I knew the difference between .equals() and == when comparing strings in a statement, but did not apply the same thought to the assertions.

Comment: @Bertie If the answer solved your problem, then accept it.